# Knockout datepicker JQueryUI - Range of days

Tags: binding, knockout.js, datepicker, addition

I want to put a maxDate within a user put days and maxDate.
So I need to add the days to the maxDate fixed by user.

```
 if(allBindingsAccessor()["rango"]){
        var dias = allBindingsAccessor().rango.dias;
        var maxrFecha =  new Date(allBindingsAccessor().rango.maxDate() + dias);
        $(element).datepicker("option", "maxDate", maxrFecha);
    }
```

On html

```
Fecha FIN: ,input type="text" data-bind="
                datepicker: fechaFin, 
                minDate: fechaIni, 
                rango: {
                    maxDate: fechaIni,
                    dias: 10}, 
                datepickerOptions: {
                    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
                }" 
            id="fechafin"  />
```

**SOLUTION**

```
if(allBindingsAccessor()["rango"]){
        var dias = allBindingsAccessor().rango.dias;
        var maxrFecha =  new Date(allBindingsAccessor().rango.maxDate());
        maxrFecha.setDate(maxrFecha.getDate()+dias);
        $(element).datepicker("option", "maxDate", maxrFecha);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked at least:

```
if(allBindingsAccessor()["rango"]){
        var dias = allBindingsAccessor().rango.dias;
        var maxrFecha =  new Date(allBindingsAccessor().rango.maxDate());
        maxrFecha.setDate(maxrFecha.getDate()+dias);
        $(element).datepicker("option", "maxDate", maxrFecha);
    }
```